# Python convert multiple lists to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 3 lists:

```
names = ["john", "paul", "george", "ringo"]
job = ["guitar", "bass", "guitar", "drums"]
status = ["dead", "alive", "dead", "alive"]
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to combine these lists into a dict like the following:

```
{"person":{"Name":"john", "Job":"guitar", "Status":"dead"}, "person":{"Name":"paul", "Job":"bass", "Status":"alive"}, "person":{"Name":"george", "Job":"guitar", "Status":"dead"}, "person":{"Name":"ringo", "Job":"drums", "Status":"alive"}}
```

I have tried using dict(zip) but cannot get it to format like above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your output makes no sense. Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys, that contradicts the purpose of a dictionary. What would result["person"] give?

Comment: Your output doesn't make much sense. You can't have duplicate keys in a dict, so you would end up with a single person inside your dict.

Comment: @bababooey92 thanks for asking this question.. i came up with the same question and found out what I really needed are the answers below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you want is a list of dictionaries. You can `zip` your three lists together and use a list comprehension. Here's an example:

```
[
    {'name': name, 'job': job, 'status': status}
    for name, job, status in zip(names, jobs, statuses)
]
```

(also renaming your `job` to `jobs` and `status` to `statuses`)

Which will give you:

```
[
  {'name': 'john', 'job': 'guitar', 'status': 'dead'},
  {'name': 'paul', 'job': 'bass', 'status': 'alive'},
  {'name': 'george', 'job': 'guitar', 'status': 'dead'},
  {'name': 'ringo', 'job': 'drums', 'status': 'alive'}
]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
>>> names = ["john", "paul", "george", "ringo"]
>>> job = ["guitar", "bass", "guitar", "drums"]
>>> status = ["dead", "alive", "dead", "alive"]
>>> persons = []
>>> for n, j, s in zip(names, job, status):
...    person = { 'name': n, 'job': j, 'status': s }
...    persons.append(person)
...
>>> persons
[{'status': 'dead', 'job': 'guitar', 'name': 'john'}, {'status': 'alive', 'job': 'bass', 'name': 'paul'}, {'status': 'dead', 'job': 'guitar', 'name': 'george'}, {'status': 'alive', 'job': 'drums', 'name': 'ringo'}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
names = ["john", "paul", "george", "ringo"]
job = ["guitar", "bass", "guitar", "drums"]
status = ["dead", "alive", "dead", "alive"]
```

two step process:

```
description =[{'job': j, 'status': s} for j,s in zip(job,status)]
artist ={n: i for n,i in zip(names,description)}}
```

final output:

```
print(artist)

{'john': {'job': 'guitar', 'status': 'dead'},
 'paul': {'job': 'bass', 'status': 'alive'},
 'george': {'job': 'guitar', 'status': 'dead'},
 'ringo': {'job': 'drums', 'status': 'alive'}}
```

you can then do something like this:

```
artist['ringo']['job']
```

output:

```
'drums'
```